# Drawing lines to a segment in a piechart using html5

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have the following function that draws a piechart. `pieValues` are the set of values to chart. `pieTotal` is the total of all the values and `colors` are an array of colors to fill the pie segment

```
function drawPieChart()
{       
    for (var i = 0; i < pieValues.length; i++) 
    {
        ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(center[0],center[1]);
        // arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise)
        ctx.arc(center[0],center[1],radius,lastPosition,lastPosition+(Math.PI*2*(pieValues[i]/pieTotal)),false);
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;     
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.lineTo(center[0],center[1]);
        ctx.fill();
        lastPosition += Math.PI*2*(pieValues[i]/pieTotal);

    }
}
```

I want to draw a line from each segment with the aim to have the value of the segment on the line.

Is there an easy way to draw a line to each segment?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is

```
var fChartY = center[1];
var fChartX = center[0];

var fChartYTo = fChartY + (radius +20)*Math.sin(lastPosition + .5);
var fChartXTo = fChartX + (radius +20)*Math.cos(lastPosition + .5);     
drawLine(fChartX, fChartY, fChartXTo, fChartYTo);
```

with `fChartY,fChartX` being the center of the piechart